# How to measure the difference in outcomes across 32 dimensions in a time-series study?

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis, matrix, intraclass-correlation

I have a dataset that recorded the contact patterns for each participant during three waves.

For example:
matrix_base_1 means that Participant 1 met with one person aged over 70 at location two, and met with three people aged between 30 to 39 at location three, and met with three people aged between 50-59 at location three... The metrics of Participant 1 for the base survey are as follows. There are another two metrics for Participant 1 for the follow-up 1 and follow-up 2 surveys.

```
Agegroup_contact      Locone Loctwo Locthree Locfour
           70+           0      1    0         0
           30-39         0      0    3         0
           50-59         1      0    3         0
           18-29         1      0    4         0
           40-49         0      0    4         0
           60-69         0      0    0         0
           5-17          0      0    0         0
           0-4           0      0    0         0
```

I have two questions:

- I want to know how the contact pattern changed over the three surveys. I calculated the Frobenius norm between three waves, norm difference1 = difference between base and follow-up 1, norm difference2 = between follow-up 1 and follow-up 2, and the sum norm difference =  norm difference1 + norm difference. Can I use the sum norm difference to indicate the variability of the contact pattern for each participant?
- Regarding the statistical analysis method, the independent variable will be the sum norm difference, and the dependent variables include sex, age, and etc. The date information is not included here because the result is not according to the time. However, I searched the literature and found that most similar study designs use time-series analysis which requires including the date information. But the result of most similar studies is one dimension, not 32 dimensions as this study and dataset. Which statistical method should I use for this study?